# how to upgrade version of codeigniter 2x to 3x

Tags: php, codeigniter

im trying to update codeigniter version from 2.2 to 3.1.
me already to following this instruction https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html
but i still get error like this.

Notice: Undefined index: log_path in C:\xampp\htdocs\simangkug\system\core\Log.php on line 127

Notice: Undefined index: log_path in C:\xampp\htdocs\simangkug\system\core\Log.php on line 127

Warning: mkdir(): Invalid path in C:\xampp\htdocs\simangkug\system\core\Log.php on line 131

what can i do to fix this problem ?
on my server using php version 7.3

Comment: It sounds like it might be a permissions problem - are you running this as local admin?

Comment: @neophytte yes im running on local admin

Comment: Did you get a solution to this issue?